# Generting specific number through php

Tags: php, mysql

When click the submit Button System will generate a Unique number:

```
yyyymmdd001
```

If the second order of the date:

```
2016/07/22
```

then system will generate:

```
20160722002
```

and So on

like third order will be `20160722003`...

How do I generate this using PHP?

The above flow will be same for date change, like today 22. So, tomorrow will be 23. So, the number will be generated by the code is like that the first order received on 23 date so the number will be `20160723001`, `20160723002`... and so on

Comment: very neat question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, try yourself first, if you get stuck any where, post here, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the current order number to this function:

```
function orderID( $orderNum ) {

  $dateStr = date( 'Ymd' );

  $orderNumStr = str_pad( $orderNum, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT );

  return $dateStr . $orderNumStr;

}
```

It will return the order ID you want.

For example,

`echo orderID( 7 );`

will return:

> 20160721007